# JavaScript map returning undefined for some elements

Tags: javascript, object, array.prototype.map

Given the following array of member data, I'm to return an array of `memberID`'s for members whose membership status not current.

Here's the member data:

```html
var members = [
  {
    firstName: 'Howard',
    lastName: 'Lee',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 235
  },
  {
    firstName: 'James',
    lastName: 'Icharis',
    membershipIsCurrent: false,
    MemberID: 236
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Thomas',
    lastName: 'Cronquist',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 237
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Philip',
    lastName: 'Grover',
    membershipIsCurrent: false,
    MemberID: 238
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Eric',
    lastName: 'Broadstone',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 239
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Hunter',
    lastName: 'Gonzales',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 240
  }];
```

Here is my code to grab that data:

```html
function lapsedIDs (array ) {
  return array.map( function ( member ) {
    if ( member.membershipIsCurrent === false ) {
      return member.MemberID;
    }
  });
}

lapsedIDs(members);
```

Here is the result.  I don't understand why it's returning **`undefined`** for each member whose membership has NOT lapsed.  Any pointers??

```html
[ undefined, 236, undefined, 238, undefined, undefined ]
```

Answer (score 9):

`map()` will create a new element for every existing one in the original array.

If you don't `return` something for all conditions a function automatically returns undefined which is what you are seeing

You could `filter()` first to remove the unwanted items and then `map()`

```
 return array.map( function ( member ) {
    return member.membershipIsCurrent
  }).map(function(member){
     return member.MemberID;
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Why this problem :- because  **.map** every time should return a value in your case if the condition is false the function return undefined because you don't provide any value to return .
What to do ? use **filter** first then use **map** look at the solution below

```js
var members = [
  {
    firstName: 'Howard',
    lastName: 'Lee',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 235
  },
  {
    firstName: 'James',
    lastName: 'Icharis',
    membershipIsCurrent: false,
    MemberID: 236
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Thomas',
    lastName: 'Cronquist',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 237
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Philip',
    lastName: 'Grover',
    membershipIsCurrent: false,
    MemberID: 238
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Eric',
    lastName: 'Broadstone',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 239
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Hunter',
    lastName: 'Gonzales',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 240
  }];
function lapsedIDs (array ) {
  return array.filter( function ( member ) {
    return member.membershipIsCurrent === false 
      
  }).map(function(member){
      return member.MemberID;
});
}


console.log(lapsedIDs(members));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map()` runs on *every* element in the source array, and maps it to something else. You aren't returning the member ID from the current members, so it maps them to `undefined`. You probably just want to modify your function to start with `let lapsedMembers = [];` and then use `forEach` instead of `map`, and in that loop just push the IDs to the `lapsedMembers` array.

```js
var members = [
  {
    firstName: 'Howard',
    lastName: 'Lee',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 235
  },
  {
    firstName: 'James',
    lastName: 'Icharis',
    membershipIsCurrent: false,
    MemberID: 236
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Thomas',
    lastName: 'Cronquist',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 237
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Philip',
    lastName: 'Grover',
    membershipIsCurrent: false,
    MemberID: 238
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Eric',
    lastName: 'Broadstone',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 239
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Hunter',
    lastName: 'Gonzales',
    membershipIsCurrent: true,
    MemberID: 240
  }];
  
function lapsedIDs ( array ) {
  let lapsedMembers = [];
  
  array.forEach(function ( member ) {
    if ( member.membershipIsCurrent === false ) {
      lapsedMembers.push(member.MemberID);
    }
  });
  
  return lapsedMembers;
}

console.log(lapsedIDs(members));
```

Answer (score 0):

That `map` wants to put *something* in the array even if your `membershipIsCurrent` test fails. So it throws in an `undefined`.

You might `filter` before your map to avoid this.

```
function lapsedIDs(array) {
    return array.filter(member => {
        return !member.membershipIsCurrent;
    }).map(member => member.MemberID);
}

lapsedIDs(members);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to fix the same problem and realized after looking at this post that the simplest solution is

```
function lapsedIDs (array ) {
    return array.map( function ( member ) {
      if ( member.membershipIsCurrent === false ) {
        return member.MemberID;
      }
    }).filter(y => y !== undefined);
}
```

In my case I don't know what the input is and I don't care, I just want the map to return all the defined values.